# Dependency injection for SerialPort class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, serial-port

I want to remove the dependecies to the `SerialPort` class and use dependency injection instead. But I don't know which interface to use. `SerialPort` implements `ICommand`, but if I use this interface, I am not able to use the `SerialPort` methods.

This is my code:

```
private readonly SerialPort _serialPort;

public CommandService(string comPort)
{
    _serialPort = new SerialPort(comPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One) { Handshake = Handshake.None };
    try
    {
        _serialPort.Open();
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Serialport { comPort } can't be found");
    }
    _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceived);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    _serialPort.Close();
}
```

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: How have you tried to implement a solution. What part caused issues?

Comment: It's the `comPort` fixe?

Comment: I tried to use an IComponent as an data type of  _serialport, but then I wasn't able to use the Serilport methods.

Comment: No comPort and the _serialPort should be not restricted to being an instance of serialport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `SerialPort` doesn't have an interface. If you want to use it with dependency injection, you will have to create your own interface and a class that implements it. This class will only be a wrapper for .NET's `SerialPort` class:

```
public class SerialPortWrapper : ISerialPortWrapper
{
    private readonly SerialPort port;

    public SerialPortWrapper(SerialPort port)
    {
       this.port = port;
    }

    public void Open()
    {
       port.Open();
    }

    public string ReadLine()
    {
       return port.ReadLine();
    }

    public void WriteLine(string line)
    {
       port.WriteLine();
    }
}

public interface ISerialPortWrapper
{
   void Open();
   string ReadLine();
   WriteLine(string line);
}
```

Use this interface in your CommandService class:

```
private readonly ISerialPortWrapper _serialPort;

public CommandService(string comPort)
   : this(new SerialPortWrapper(new SerialPort(comPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One) { Handshake = Handshake.None }))
{
}

public CommandService(ISerialPortWrapper serialPortWrapper)
{
    _serialPort = serialPortWrapper;

    try
    {
        _serialPort.Open();
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Serialport { comPort } can't be found");
    }
}
```

I shortened everything for brevity, but I hope you get the idea.